# How can i make the alphabet beautiful? (web)

Tags: website-design, typography, interface-design, text

I'm working on a directory type of page where I will have your typical "A B C D E ..." alphabet posted on top so people can jump down to listings starting with their letter of choice.

The alphabet just looks really boring and I'm looking for ideas or solutions to how i can make it look better.

I'm open to any solutions ranging from graphic design changes, fonts, jquery plugins, etc

Thank you.

Comment: What age group is the website going to be for? and is there a specific theme?

Comment: General idea-gathering and brainstorming questions are off-topic per the FAQ.

Comment: I actually think this is a great question! The alphabet really *is* rather boring to look at, and it seems a challenge to make an adult think such a thing can look beautiful while still keeping it functional.

Comment: I wanted to take up this challenge despite the fact that it was closed. This is what I came up with: http://misc.BHStudios.org/SSCCE/prettyAlphabet/

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend using  the CSS3 @font-face + pick the font that suit your needs from Google Fonts directory.
if are totally new to such technique,simply follow the instructions at the [getting started](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html) page on Google Web Fonts API :

Comment: Just to be clear -- are you proposing that i just lay out the letters in a horizontal stripe using a nice font?  Thank you for responding btw!